# Replicate softmax of pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, softmax

I am trying to implement the softmax function in pytorch, but cant get the output of my implementation to match the output of pytorch's implementation.

I am trying to do this because I would like to go on to implement a masked softmax that would not include certain indices in the sum for the denominator, and set the output for those masked indexes.

I would like to calculate this for a matrix where each row in the output sums to 1. My current implentation is :

```
def my_softmax(x):
    exp = x.exp()
    return exp / exp.sum(1, keepdim=True)
```

However the output isnt the same for my implementation and pytorch's:

```
>>> t = torch.randn(3, 2)
>>> t
tensor([[-1.1881, -0.1085],
        [ 0.5825,  1.0719],
        [-0.5309, -1.3774]])
>>> my_softmax(t)
tensor([[0.2536, 0.7464],
        [0.3800, 0.6200],
        [0.6998, 0.3002]])
>>> t.softmax(1)
tensor([[0.2536, 0.7464],
        [0.3800, 0.6200],
        [0.6998, 0.3002]])
>>> my_softmax(t) == t.softmax(1)
tensor([[False,  True],
        [False, False],
        [ True,  True]])
```

Why do these different implementations produce different results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```
import torch

def my_softmax(x):

    means = torch.mean(x, 1, keepdim=True)[0]
    x_exp = torch.exp(x-means)
    x_exp_sum = torch.sum(x_exp, 1, keepdim=True)

    return x_exp/x_exp_sum

t = torch.randn(3, 2) 

s1 = my_softmax(t)
s2 = t.softmax(1)
```

```
print(torch.allclose(s1, s2))
True
```

P.S. taken from discussion
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-implement-the-exactly-same-softmax-as-f-softmax-by-pytorch/44263

Comment: For stability reasons I think you would rather take the maximum value not the average.

Comment: I dont understand `means = torch.mean(x, 1, keepdim=True)[0]` why do we take the mean of the first row using `[0]` then take this from every element in the matrix `x`? Wouldnt we just take the mean of each indifivual row i.e. omit the `[0]`? also what is the purpose of this mean centering anyway? This is not shown in the formula for softmax, is it to do with numerical precision being greater closer to 0?

Comment: Agree with @Ivan about maximum value instead of mean.

OP, yes it is for numerical stability. please read these notes from stanford https://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#softmax

Comment: So we want to use the max so that the largest value is 0 meaning that the highest value in the tensor outputted but `torch.exp` will be 1. Keeping the magnitudes close to 0 where floating point representations are more dense. Why do we select the max value from the first row though, using `[0]`? Would it not be better to use the max value for each vector, or the maximum across all dimensions?